# Adding a commit from a fork to a topic branch

Tags: git, github

If `userA` and I both fork a project from `userB`. Then `userA` creates a commit in their master fork and has not decided to make a pull request to `userB` master. How do I add their commit (`userA`) to my dev branch (not my master) in my fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this with one command. For example:

```
git pull https://github.com/userA/repo.git master
```

This will merge userA's `master` branch into your current branch (use `git checkout dev` on your own repository first).

If you find yourself doing this frequently, you can [add a remote](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-remote.html) to your local repository that allows you to refer to userA's repository with a single name. For example:

```
git remote add userA https://github.com/userA/repo.git
git pull userA master
```

Comment: Does this leave any info or meta about `userA` in my dev branch? with `git log` I don't mind but basically I just want the few code changes from the single commit the user did instead of being ugly with copy pasting or copy files (which doesn't seem very git like) so that I can continue and pick up the work on fixing the issue the user was working on from the master

Comment: Yeah, you may get merge conflicts whenever you do a merge. Fortunately, Git makes them reasonably easy to resolve. I recommend [Pro Git](http://progit.org/) as good background reading.